# GoLang - Iterate over data to unmarshal multiple YAML structures

Tags: go, yaml

I am fairly new to Golang, please excuse my newbyness.

I am currently using yaml.v2 package (https://github.com/go-yaml/yaml) to unmarshal YAML data into structs.

Consider the following example code:

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"
  "log"
)

type Container struct {
  First  string
  Second struct {
    Nested1 string
    Nested2 string
    Nested3 string
    Nested4 int
  }
}

var data = `
  first: first value
  second:
    nested1: GET
    nested2: /bin/bash
    nested3: /usr/local/bin/customscript
    nested4: 8080

  first: second value
  second:
    nested1: POST
    nested2: /bin/ksh
    nested3: /usr/local/bin/customscript2
    nested4: 8081
`

func main() {

  container := Container{}

  err := yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &container)
  if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("error: %v", err)
  }
  fmt.Printf("---values found:\n%+v\n\n", container)

}
```

The result:

```
---values found: {First:second value Second:{Nested1:POST Nested2:/bin/ksh Nested3:/usr/local/bin/customscript2 Nested4:8081}}
```

This is as expected, the unmarshal function finds one occurrence of the YAML data.

What I would like to do is write a simple while/each/for loop that loops through the data variable and marshals all the occurrences into seperate Container structs. How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple change to accomplish what you want is to have the data in the `yaml` be items in an array, then Unmarshal into a slice of `Container`

```
var data = `
- first: first value
  second:
    nested1: GET
    nested2: /bin/bash
    nested3: /usr/local/bin/customscript
    nested4: 8080

- first: second value
  second:
    nested1: POST
    nested2: /bin/ksh
    nested3: /usr/local/bin/customscript2
    nested4: 8081
`

func main() {

    container := []Container{}

    err := yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &container)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error: %v", err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("---values found:\n%+v\n\n", container)

}

---values found:
[{First:first value Second:{Nested1:GET Nested2:/bin/bash Nested3:/usr/local/bin/customscript Nested4:8080}} {First:second value Second:{Nested1:POST Nested2:/bin/ksh Nested3:/usr/local/bin/customscript2 Nested4:8081}}]
```